# Why is my simple C++ "What is your name?" program not working?

Tags: c++, undeclared-identifier

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgcfn.png)

I keep getting the "undeclared identifier" error but I don't know what that means or how to fix this. Forgive me I am new to this!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void);
     //Not sure why there is a Parse issue?
{
     // insert code here...
     cout<< "Hello, what is your name?";
     cin>> Scotty;

     cout<< "Hello, "<<Scotty<<endl;

     return0;
 }
```

I was able to figure out the previous question of the undeclared identifier but now I am getting an 'Expected unqualified-id' error? Thanks for answering to those who have

Comment: you can copy the source code here you know

Comment: `Scotty` is not declared yet as a variable

Comment: How would I declare Scotty as a variable?

Comment: You really should be reviewing basic syntax rules for your language of choice when you are learning. Learn to google error messages as well to aid in debugging. Specifically for c++ you can use cplusplus as a search term

Comment: you need to declare `Scotty` by adding the statement `string Scotty;` before the `cin` statement.  Also, `cin>>Scotty>>` is not valid syntax, change that line to `cin>>Scotty;`

Comment: In the future, you should paste your code into your stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

string Scotty;
cout << " Hello what is your name";
cin >> Scotty;

cout <<"\nHello"<<Scotty<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared variable named Scotty. You must declare variables before use them so you must declare by adding `string Scotty;` before calling cin. Also you must replace the operator `>>` at the end of cin line to `;`